# Uploading multiple files with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webclient

I need to upload multiple files in a winforms application. So far I've been using a webclient and while this is working fine I'm wondering if there is a better way for doing this. Does the webclient make a new connection for every request or does the connection persists between uploads?

```
Dim Ftpclient As New System.Net.WebClient()
Ftpclient.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)

Dim Files As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

''//Fill dictionary with items for upload here

For Each RemoteFile As String In Files.Keys
    Ftpclient.UploadFile(RemoteFile, Files(RemoteFile))
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll create a new TCP connection for every file, because it's way HTTP works.

IMHO, not a bad thing in your scenario.

Comment: It's not quite the way FTP works.  Still, System.Net doesn't offer an alternative to keeping the command port connection opened.

Comment: sure, but note OP create a `System.Net.WebClient` instance, not `System.Net.FtpWebRequest`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what protocl you are using for upload. If you are using HTTP, then the client will reuse the previous connection if it can. I am not sure about FTP - I think FTP also supports keep-alive.

In any case, if you are concerned about performance, you should use Wireshark to see how the connection usage is being accomplished. Is it creating a new connection everytime?